# add link to all divs with a certain class

Tags: javascript

Here's hopefully a simple request. I just can't seem to get the mechanics of this working. I'm trying to find all `div`s with a certain class on a page and add an href to them. The code I have so far that doesn't seem to work is below.

```
function FBcheck() {
elements = document.getElementsByClassName('friend-icon');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
elements[i].href = "http://www.example.com";
}}
```

Comment: Are the targeted elements anchors `a`? ... they need to be for the link to work.

Comment: Divs can't have href attributes, only anchors can

Comment: Please elaborate on *doesn't seem to work*. Share a working snippet demonstrating the error.

Comment: You cannot add href attribute to a div. You can add it only to a. Do you want to insert a link inside each of those divs?

Comment: Yes technocloud. or even a button with the link on it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you cant assign `href` property to `div` it should be assign to anchor element,

And other issue is you have used incorrect selector with `.`, use `friend-icon` selector instead of `.friend-icon`

see below is updated code snippet,

```js
function FBcheck() {
      elements = document.getElementsByClassName('friend-icon');    
      for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
              elements[i].href = "http://www.example.com";
      }}
FBcheck()
```

```html
<a class="friend-icon">1</a >
<a class="friend-icon">1</a >
<a class="friend-icon">1</a >
<a class="friend-icon">1</a >
<a class="friend-icon">1</a >
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to all of you for pointing out that you can't add an href to a div! This code is doing what I need it to.

```
function FJcheck() {
elements = document.getElementsByClassName('friend-icon');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
var aTag = document.createElement('a'); 
aTag.setAttribute('href', \"https://www.facebook.com\"); 
aTag.innerHTML = \"FB Link\"; 
elements[i].appendChild(aTag);}}
```